# Modal Application

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, kiosk-mode

I'm using Xamarin.Android and I would like to build an application that start in modal way and don't close if you push the home button.
So this application need to be the only one application than a user can use on device.

Somebody can suggest how it can be done?

Comment: There's a discussion on the Xam forums about this here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/426/persistant-app

Answer (score 1):

You best way to do is to make a "Launcher"/"Home" application. The Android SDK comes with a sample on how to do this.

You basically do this by adding your main `Activity` to the `android.intent.category.HOME` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` category and you set the `launchMode` to `singleInstance`.

This will register it as a `Home` application, then when you press your home button it should ask you to choose which launcher you want to use. You will have to set it once and it can be changed by the user.

You can find the sample in: `android-sdk\samples\android-17\Home\src\com\example\android\home` (should also be available in the other API samples).

Answer (score 0):

You cant stop people from installing applications on android devices. You would have to build your own hardware for that however, you can override OnKeyTouch and check for the key being home.

You could build a service that checks the package of each running application and log which applications are run on the device to prevent users from using company property on other things. However, if android ever decides to kill your application the service should stop and this wont work.

Long story short what you are trying to do is flawed in its inception given the platform you are trying to do it on.